# When is the distance in the Electric Field formula squared?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law, coulombs-law

I've been studying electricity and when I reached the electric field, I found myself in a bit of a problem.
I found two different formulas that seem to contradict each other

> $$E = \frac{V}{x}$$

and

> $$E = \frac{Kq}{x^2}$$

The second formula I understand is used to calculate the electric field produced by one charge particle (Using Coulomb's Law). The first one however, I've seen it used when calculating the Electric Field produced by capacitors (I am not sure if this conclusion is correct, that's what I've observed trying to solve capacitor related problems).
I don't undesrtand why they're two separate formulas, and even if I try to go from the second formula to the first, I always end up with

> $$E = \frac{V}{x^2}$$

which is wrong. So basically the question is, are both formulas correct? Are they both applicable? Or does it depends on the case? (Whether we're talking about capacitors, particles, that sort of thing)

Comment: Where did you see the first of these?

Comment: Indeed the first is not an electric field, are you confusing the potential with the electric field perhaps?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not show sufficient research effort.

Comment: @VincentThacker Perhaps it might help to tell the OP what they should look into to improve the post. FWIW I don't think the issue is "lack of research" (I think this could be a valid question), but I think it's not very clear. The OP should specify the context in which each formula is found.

Comment: OP the inverse square law is the correct one.

Comment: @VincentThacker On the contrary, it looks like the OP was actually trying to look up this information and got confused.

Comment: Exaclty, like @BioPhysicist said. I made a mistake on the post. What I found was that the formula of the electric field is E = V/d when there's a "constante field".(My mistake was writing K*q instead of V). I think my confusion comes from the concept of "constant field"

Comment: @LimaLimon I am voting to reopen the question. But please edit your confusion into the post to make it more clear.

Comment: Thank you @BioPhysicist, I've edited the question. I hope it's clearer now

Comment: @LimaLimon I strongly advise against blindly looking at formulae without understanding what they mean. How is a capacitor related to a point charge in the first place, and why do you think their fields should be the same? If you cannot answer this fundamental question, you should revisit Coulomb's Law in integral form, $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}) = (1/4\pi\epsilon_0) \int \text{d}^3 \mathbf{r}' \rho(\mathbf{r}') \left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}' \right)/\left|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}' \right|^3$ and rethink whether the charge distribution $\rho(\mathbf{r}')$ is the same for both situations.

Answer (score 1):

The error is that the relation $E = \frac{V}{x}$ is only precisely true when V changes uniformly throughout space. More generally, $E = -\frac{d}{dx}V$.

For a point charge, V goes as $\frac{Kq}{x}$

In fact, you'll notice if you plug in $\frac{Kq}{x}$ for $V$ you'll get

$E = \frac{Kq}{x^2} = \frac{Kq}{x} \cdot\frac{1}{x} = V\cdot\frac{1}{x} = \frac{V}{x}$

Which is the same as $E = -\frac{d}{dx}V = - \frac{Kq}{x} = \frac{Kq}{x^2}$. This only true because it's a derivative of power 1/-1 (i.e. $\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = \frac{f}{x}$ if $f(x)$ is to the power $x$ or $x^{-1}$